# how to find the ids of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

The below model is working

```
anonymous = AnonymousCustomer.where(email: 'testmail@yahoo.in').ids
```

The above returns something like this `[26, 27]`

But to find the associated record id how can I do it

I tried

```
anonymous = AnonymousCustomer.where(email: 'testmail@yahoo.in').select("post_id")
```

The above query throwing result as

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AnonymousCustomer id: nil, post_id: 289>, #<AnonymousCustomer id: nil, post_id: 290>]>
```

But the expected output is `[289, 290]` can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `anonymous = AnonymousCustomer.where(email: 'prabhaapitest@yahoo.in').pluck(:post_id
)`